# Which circuit design application is Arduino using here?

Tags: schematics

I've been looking for this software for quite a bit but can't.

It's used on Arduino articles such as [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/ShiftOut):
[image]

Does anybody know what this is called? The interface is definitely there and pretty enough for hobbyists.

Comment: Think you're looking for Fritzing

Comment: Whatever it is make sure it can export schematics from those cartoons. We get questions on this site where those diagrams are posted instead of schematics and they are almost useless for showing the ^schema^ and design intent. They're analogous to a child's colour by numbers book.

Comment: it does not quite look like frizing